# Magento grouped products are not displaying front end

Tags: magento

I have created grouped products in magento and associated some 3 products in that group.How to display that group in front end

Answer (score 0):

Nortmally magento have a group product display is basic functionality but if there is 3 option that hidding it

1. cant manage inventory
2. can not assign to category
3. product status enable disable

check above 3 setting I am sure it will start displaying

Thanks |
Chetan |
www.metizsoft.com

Comment: Inventory,category and product status everything was enabled and assigned properly.still i cant get any result in front end.where we can see the grouped product result? @ptlchetan